# How to avoid duplicate script tags when creating custom Html helper extensions in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am creating a Html helper extension to render a custom file upload control. For some client side functionality to work i need this script to be present when my helper is used.

```
function CheckSize(fileSize,id)
{
   var fileElement = document.getElementById(id);

   if (fileElement .files !== undefined) {
            var megaBytes = (fileInputs[0].files[0].size / 1024) / 1024;

            if (megaBytes > fileSize) {
                //Do Something
            }
}
```

To ensure this script is present i will have to insert it in the Html helper as seen below.

```
 public static class UploadControlExtensions
  {
    public static string UploadControl(this HtmlHelper helper, 
    UploadControlSettings settings)
    {

        string script = GetScript();
        string html = string.format("<input id='{0}'
        onchange='CheckSize({0},{1})'",settings.Id,setting.MaxSize);


        return script + html;
    }
  }
```

This is fine if there is only one instance of my control on the page but if there are multiple instances then the same script gets inserted into the page multiple times.

Is there an elegant way to ensure only one version of my script is inserted? I know i can add it to my project seperatly but i would rather that my HtmlHelper extension class deals with all that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store state in `ViewData` like:

```
public static class UploadControlExtensions
{
    public static string UploadControl(this HtmlHelper helper, UploadControlSettings settings)
    {
        var viewData = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ViewData;
        string script = String.Empty;
        if (!viewData.ContainsKey("UploadScriptPresent"))
        {
            script = GetScript();
            viewData.Add("UploadScriptPresent", true);
        }
        string html = string.format("<input id='{0}' onchange='CheckSize({0},{1})'", settings.Id, setting.MaxSize);

        return script + html;
    }
}
```